# Sharepoint Action List - Due date wrongly converted probqbly due to timezone

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have deployed an action lis with a kind of dashboard. Through this, I would like to highlight the overdue action by adding the status on a dedicated column via javascript. My full script works well except the line where I want to get the Due Date.
For trying to identify the issue, I have simply copied the Due Date in an other column (check column), and the result is surprising!!!

Examples:

```
Due Date as displawed in the pop-up > Check column interpreted by the JS code
-30/07/2016>27/07/2016 22:00:00
-16/08/2016>17/08/2016 22:00:00
-01/08/2016>03:08:2016 22:00:00
```

Find hereafter an extract of the code:

```
        var Status = oListItem.get_item('Status');
        duedate = oListItem.get_item('DueDate');
        oListItem.set_item('Check', oListItem.get_item('DueDate'));
```

It seems that the issue is related to the orignial Due Date column, qnd linked to a wrong conversion.
Does someone have an idea how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution or work around:

1. Create a calculated field which recreate the date from the Due Date field
2. In the JS, get the string from the calculated field, and then split it, et recreate the date with the JS code

Have fun!